# Sony Gold Bluetooth headset works on Windows but i can't use volume slider to control it

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth, headphones, playstation

I have a [Sony Gold Wireless headset](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/accessories/audio/gold-wireless-stereo-headset/) and it works perfectly fine, the only issue is that the windows volume Control (the slide in the task bark) doesn't affect it at all. So in order to change the volume i have to either use the built-in buttons of the headset, or whatever software am currently using, this is not a critical issue but am very used to the volume buttons i have in the keyboard (specially the "Mute" button).

What i tried so far :

- Making it the default playback device : 
  [image]
- Enabling bluetooth services : 
  [image]

I also tried using the "troubleshoot tool" and updating the driver, nothing solved this issue, because like i said, the headset is playing Sound correctly, its just that somehow it overwrite windows sound control or something.

Also did some comparison with my Razer headset and i noticed something a bit weird,

In my other Windows-10 pc, when playing *AC/DC - Highway to hell* solo on full volume, the playback device volume bars looks like this :

[image]

Playing the exact same song from the exact same source (Spotify) with full volume and also with the Razer headset, the volume bars don't get passed "4-5 bars" even thought that in my ears it's as loud as the other computer :

[image]

And for the sony Headset, it shows the same result in the "bad" and "good" PC (can't pass 4-5 bars) :

[image]

I have no idea if this can help or even if it has any meaning but I just noticed that its kinda weird, even when i use the speakers the volume bars are always limited to "4-5 bars".

But again, my main issue is that i want this slider

[image]

to work, Cause even that its set to Mute, Windows is still doing a tons of Sound.

Thank you

**Edit**

Totally forgot to say that am running :

Windows 10 - Pro; Version 1607

**Edit 2**

Another thing that i forgot, using the volume mixer has some strange results too,
changing the volume of an individual software works perfectly :

in this screenshot

[image]

I was able to reduce Spotify volume to ~30%.

Then i took it back to match main system volume (100%) and then reduced the whole System volume

[image]

,and as always, absolutely no effect, even when its muted.

Comment: Why are you comparing a PS headset to a PC headset?

Comment: @Ramhound the Razer is also a ps4 headset, i actually bought it for the ps4 until i wanted to play wirelessly, also am comparing just to showcase some "weird result" but that is not the main issue, the issue is that windows is fully recognizing a device, but simply wont control its system volume, cause the windows volume has nothing to do with the actual hardware settings in the device, you can have a speak at full volume but still able to mute it from the system, i can't do that with the bluetooth headset

Comment: Honestly it just sounds like a limitation of your PC.  The Kraken is working because it's a generic USB sound device.  It sounds like your Sony headset is simply not being detected 100% correctly

Comment: Try enabling virtual surround sound (properties of your sound device) within Sound

Comment: enabling virtual surround don't do anything

Comment: Cannot believe this has never been resolved - I'm having the same problem, exactly. I don't want to use NirCmd - I want Microsoft Windows to work. But it doesn't and one day we will hopefully not be tied to MS or Windows to play games or do anything else we want to do. We can but hope.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, but I managed with a workarround to make the media keys to affect the sound.

I installed the NirCmd, a nice utillity for windows where you can run a specific command as *change the volume for a specific application* (or the current one). What I did:

- Installed NirCmd and added to the Windows Directory (to run from anywhere)
- Created two scripts: "Volume+.bat" and "Volume-.bat" with the following contents:

Volume+

> ```
> nircmd changeappvolume Spotify.exe +0.1
> nircmd changeappvolume focused +0.1
> ```

Volume-

> ```
> nircmd changeappvolume Spotify.exe -0.1
> nircmd changeappvolume focused -0.1
> ```

Then, using the AutoHotKey app, I created this config:

```
Volume_Up:: Run, pathtobat\volume+.bat, , Hide
Volume_Down:: Run, pathtobat\volume-.bat, ,Hide
RETURN
```

Now, using the media keys feels very natural, affecting the backgroud music and the active window.

Comment: thanks man! never heard of nircmd its gonna be very useful

Comment: hey man, the "nircmd changeappvolume Spotify.exe +0.1" doesn't do anything (running the command directly without auto hot key) any idea what's going on ?

Comment: Any error? Try other nircmd commands. The command should work, even without AutoHotKey.

Comment: no error, i just tested other commands and they work, this appvolume thing doesn't work, does it still function for you ? thanks

Comment: Yeah, just tested on Spotify and worked fine.https://imgur.com/a/iOAWF

Comment: Tried with ADM rights?